# Telegram Bot, how to send a phone number as a link on a message

Tags: laravel, api, bots, telegram

I'm trying to send a message with a phone number as a link. Is there a way to acomplish that? I'm using the [Laravel Telegram Bot API](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk)

```
public function start( $telegram, $chatid ) {

        $keyboard = [
            ['Continue'],
        ];

        $reply_markup = Telegram::replyKeyboardMarkup([
            'keyboard' => $keyboard,
            'resize_keyboard' => true,
            'one_time_keyboard' => true
        ]);

        $text = "<b>¡Hola!</b> " . config('constants.emojis.waving-hand') .
            " Hey I'm Bot. " . config('constants.emojis.hug-face') .
            "\nPlease chose some option" .
            config('constants.emojis.glass') . "\nOr contact us at <a href='tel:018099999999'>HEREÍ</a> to talk with an specialist.";
        $this->sendMessage( $telegram, $chatid, $text, $reply_markup );

    }
```

Also here is my send message function

```
public function sendMessage( $telegram, $chatid, $text, $reply_markup ) {

    if ( !is_null( $reply_markup ) ) {

        $response = $telegram->sendMessage([
          'chat_id' => $chatid,
          'text' => $text,
          'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
          'reply_markup' => $reply_markup
        ]);

    } else {

        $response = $telegram->sendMessage([
          'chat_id' => $chatid,
          'text' => $text,
          'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
        ]);

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the phone number with `plus` and `country` code:

**+98**9123456789

if you use that format, telegram automatically link the number!

Comment: But what if I need to send a text instead of a phone. So when I click that text, I can go to the linked phone number

Comment: you can wrap the text (phone number, url, etc) in a HTML tag (bold, italic, ...), so the link display as unlinked text.

Comment: I know there is a way to do it in markdown as follows: `[+79991234567](tel:+79991234567)`, but I mean, I need that the link says something like `Click here`, I have tried this `[Click here](tel:+79991234567)` but i don't get anything.

Comment: `tel:` protocol is acceptable in HTML5, but in telegram you can only use `http://`, `https://`, `tg://`protocol as you can see in bot API.